I had my 6 months old female spayed and her 6 months ol nod brother neutered can they still have sexual intercourse or get pregnant
I had my 6 months old female spayed and her brother neutered about 2 weeks ago can they still have intercourse and get pregnant

The reproductive organs of both animals have been removed. The male no longer has testes, and the female no longer has ovaries or a uterus. Pregnancy is completely impossible in this circumstance, and the lack of hormones for both and a heat cycle for the female means it's very unlikely they will attempt to mate.
